# Сохранить массив в БД поэлементно (массив в строку)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli

Помогите записать массив в БД. Таблица есть. Подключение к БД есть. В форме есть поля с одинаковыми данными для массива (дата, номер, имя) и есть динамически создаваемые поля. Форма:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input name='datestamp[]'/><input name='numbe[]r'/><input name='name'[]/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name='prod[]'/><input name='artikul[]'/><input name='price[]'/><button>ДОБАВИТЬ СТРОКУ</button>//ДИНАМИЧЕСКИЕ ПОЛЯ
        </tr>
    </table>
<input type="hidden" name='prod_id]'>
<button type="submit'>Send</button>
</form>
```

кусок кода контроллера:

```
public function insert(Request $request){
    $id= $request->input('prod_id');
    $datestamp= $request->input('datestamp');
    $number= $request->input('number');
    $name= $request->input('name');
    $prod= $request->input('prod');
    $artikul= $request->input('artikul');
    $price= $request->price('artikul');
foreach ($request as $id){
    DB::insert('insert into supplys (datestamp,number,name,prod,artikult,price)
 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [$datestamp,$number,$name,$prod,$artikul,$price])
};
return redirect () -> route ( 'new' );
}
```

пробовал такой вариант в контроллере:

```
$price= $request['artikul']
```

Ошибка Array to string conversion. JSON не подходит - в примере обрезанная форма. По факту она  намного больше и  нужно каждый элемент в соотв. столбец таблицы. 
В чем ошибка? Признателен за любую мысль!

Comment: может массив `[$datestamp,$number,$name,$prod,$artikul,$price]` преобразовать в строку с помощью `implode`?

Comment: Как я понимаю синтаксис преобразования такой $row= implode(",", $array); . Брыкается все одно - ErrorException
Array to string conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание, что у Вас в форме есть несколько ошибок(Может это при вставке кода в данном сообществе из-за спешки вышло):
`numbe[]r` = `number[]`
`'name'[]` = `'name[]'`
`'prod_id]'` = `'prod_id[]'`
`type="submit'` = `type="submit"`
Забыли точку с запятой в 
`DB::insert('insert into supplys (datestamp,number,name,prod,artikult,price)
 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [$datestamp,$number,$name,$prod,$artikul,$price]);`
Так же не совсем понятно, с какой целью Вы используете `foreach ($request as $id){` Хотя `$id` у Вас нигде не используется.

Полученные данные у Вас являются массивами, так как у Вас может быть несколько данных полей(Добавление через **"Добавить строку"**).

По этому Вам необходимо использовать подход перебора массивов
Вы можете попробовать следующий подход:

```php
    for ($i=0;$i<count($datestamp);$i++){
        DB::insert('insert into supplys (datestamp,number,name,prod,artikult,price)
 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [$datestamp[$i],$number[$i],$name[$i],$prod[$i],$artikul[$i],$price[$i]]);
};
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. В форме все нормально, спасибо за замечания, опечатки в спешке. По вашему коду ошибка ErrorException Undefined offset: 1. В связи с этим сразу возникает вопрос - это может быть связано с тем, что массив выглядит так (сокращен) [ datestamp=>('2020-20-03'),number=>('3'), name=>('cat', 'pet')]. Т.е. в массиве есть значения из полей с одним значением (напр дата) и несколькими (напр. имя)?

Comment: И забыл указать - в БД идет запись, но только первая строка.

Answer (score 0):

работающий код :

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($datestamp);$i++){
        DB::insert('insert into supplys (datestamp,number,name,prod,artikult,price)
 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [$datestamp[0],$number[0],$name[$i],$prod[$i],$artikul[$i],$price[$i]]);
};
```

0 - там где при переборе данные в  единственном числе.